# Service Hooks messages stuck in queue or processing state

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

After upgrade to TFS 2018 Update 2 (with Azure DevOps 2019 still persisting), some service hooks messages are not sent correctly but are stuck in the queue with status `Queued` or `Processing` (see the image). Messages in `Processing` state appear to be delivered correctly to the receiver, the ones in `Queued` state not. Service hooks are working for 1-2 days correctly after a restart, next days are more and more buggy. Receiver side is ok, many times tested.

[image]

This happens on all service hooks (some are HTTP webhooks, other posts to Teams), in 2 of our 3 collections. On the 3rd collection, it works without issues. Disable/Enable or recreating the hook doesn't help. Is there any way how to debug service hooks or some log.

Also reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/269079/service-hooks-messages-stuck-in-queue-or-processin.html). Received several patches from MS but with the same result. Installed Azure DevOps 2019 with the same results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - this is a Microsoft and TFS problem. After several months of communication with Microsoft and trying several patches for this problem, finally, the right patch arrived. And the problem is solved.

The patch is non-public now, so if you are experiencing a similar problem, ask Microsoft support.

Edit: Problem is fixed also in official release 2019.0.1. See [Release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops)